# String.replace Without Destroying DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, dom, replace

I have an element that contains sub-strings of the form: `{%paramName%}` that i want to replace using regex.

I have used `$('#element').html().replace();` but soon found out that although this does what i want , it destroys information like `$('#element').data()` , and other non-serializable data.

How can I replace this pattern in : tag names , tag attributes , tag.innerHTML without destroying the DOM ?

Comment: Recursion. Loop through all nodes and replace as necessary.

Comment: *"How can I replace this pattern in : tag names..."* You can't change an element's tag name after creating it, you have to *replace* the element. The rest of it is, as Niet says, simply a recursive traversal.